# Ractive/C# MVC - Building Multiple Form Fields

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, ractivejs

I'm using ractive 0.7.3

I'm trying to build a form out of a filled ractive Object.

The Form is built correctyl but if i change a text input value to 1 the input field changes to a checkbox input field. And the checkboxes are not working proberly too.

What is wrong there? Sorry for the little chaotic ractive, i've tried a lot of things to get this working.

The double @@ must be used because it`s a MVC Project.

```
{{#each memberdata:i}}
  {{#if this === '1'}}
     <div class="item"><label for="checkbox{{@@index}}">{{@@key}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox{{@@index}}" value="{{this}}" checked="{{this}}" /> </div>
  {{elseif @@key === 'Id' ||  @@key === 'UId' }}
     <div class="item" style="font-size:18px;font-family:Verdana, helvetica, sans-serif;"><b>{{@@key}}:</b> {{this}}</div>
  {{elseif @@key === 'Email' || @@key == 'Title' || @@key === 'FirstName' || @@key === 'LastName'}}
     <div class="item" style="font-size:14px;font-family:Verdana, helvetica, sans-serif;"><b>{{@@key}}:</b> <input type="text" id="txt{{@@index}}" name="{{@@key}}" value="{{.}}" style="float:right; padding-right:15px;" /></div>
  {{elseif @@key === 'SalutationGerman'}}
     <div class="item" style="font-size:14px;font-family:Verdana, helvetica, sans-serif;"><b>Anrede:</b> <input type="text" id="txt{{@@index}}" name="{{key}}" value="{{.}}" style="float:right; padding-right:15px;" /></div>
  {{elseif @@key == 'DateOfFirstRegistration' || @@key === 'CustomerId'}}
    {{#if !this}}
       <div class="item"><b>{{@@key}}:</b>Kein Eintrag</div>
    {{else}}
       <div class="item"><b>{{@@key}}:</b> {{.}}</div>
    {{/if}}
  {{else}}
    <div class="item"><label for="checkbox{{@@index}}">{{@@key}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox{{@@index}}" value="{{.}}" checked="{{.}}" /> </div>
  {{/if}}{{/each}}
```

Comment: I advise making a jsfiddle example. It would make it easier to reproduce / analyze / fix.

Comment: Can you JSON.stringify memberdata? The first conditional is checking to see if the current value is '1', and if it is, rendering a checkbox. That explains the why the input immediately switches to a checkbox when you type '1'.